# High loss rate for unknow reason when training CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have stuck in the assignment for three days and checked everything I could get from the internet. but the loss rate of my model cannot be reduced. The model is just random guessing the validation dataset.

(data source)[https://www.kaggle.com/datamunge/sign-language-mnist]

Here are some methods I have tried and verified that don't work:

- increasing **batch size**, but the batch size seems to be irrelevant to the high loss rate and low accuracy.
- check the **format** of input data, but I found nothing, everything seems to work properly.
- try to remove **image augmentation**, the loss rate doesn't care.
- try to **change optimizer**, I have tried Adam, RMSDrop, SGD.
- try to add **more neurons** and **increase epoch** of training, only increase the training accuracy but not validation accuracy.
- check my **environment**, I have run other sample codes of CNN and they worked as expected.

Here is my code and output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from os import getcwd
import sys


def progressbar(it, prefix="", size=29, file=sys.stdout):
    # This def is made by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207193/iambr
    # it is the list you are going to iterate
    # prefix is the title of your progress bar
    # size is the length of your progress bar
    count = len(it)

    def show(j):
        x = int(size*j/count)
        file.write("%s[%s%s%s] %i/%i\r" %
                   (prefix, "="*x, ">", "."*(size-x), j, count))
        file.flush()
    show(0)
    for i, item in enumerate(it):
        yield item
        show(i+1)
    file.write("\n")
    file.flush()


def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as training_file:
        images = np.empty((0, 28, 28), dtype=float)
        labels = np.empty((0), dtype=float)
        # Your code starts here
        raw_file = np.loadtxt(training_file.readlines()[
                              :-1], dtype=float, skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
        for row in progressbar(raw_file, "Loading data: "):
            if(len(row) == 785):
                labels = np.append(labels, row[0])
                image = np.reshape(row[1:785], (1, 28, 28))
                images = np.append(image, images, axis=0)
        print(f'read file:{filename} complete')
        return images, labels


# full data set
# path_sign_mnist_train = f'{getcwd()}/tmp2/sign_mnist_train.csv'
# path_sign_mnist_test = f'{getcwd()}/tmp2/sign_mnist_test.csv'

# reduce training set
path_sign_mnist_train = f'{getcwd()}/tmp2/sign_mnist_train_a.csv'
path_sign_mnist_test = f'{getcwd()}/tmp2/sign_mnist_test_a.csv'

training_images, training_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_train)
testing_images, testing_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_test)

training_images=training_images/255.
testing_images=testing_images/255.

# Keep these
print(training_images.shape)
print(training_labels.shape)
print(testing_images.shape)
print(testing_labels.shape)
print(testing_labels)

# Testing code
plt.imshow(training_images[1], interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
print(training_labels[1])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
   featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=14,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        zoom_range = 0.09, # Randomly zoom image 
        width_shift_range=0.14,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.14,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=False,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False,   # randomly flip images
        brightness_range = (0.8, 1.0),  # brightness of image
        rescale = 1. / 255.)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)

training_images = np.reshape(training_images, (-1,28,28,1))
train_datagen.fit(training_images)
testing_images = np.reshape(testing_images,(-1,28,28,1))

training_labels=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(training_labels,num_classes=25)
testing_labels=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(testing_labels, num_classes=25)

batch_size = 16

train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
    training_images,
    training_labels, batch_size=batch_size)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow(
    testing_images,
    testing_labels, batch_size=batch_size)
# Keep These
print(training_images.shape)
print(testing_images.shape)

# Their output should be:
# (27455, 28, 28, 1)
# (7172, 28, 28, 1)

# Define the model
# Use no more than 2 Conv2D and 2 MaxPooling2D
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Your Code Here
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile Model.
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.005),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# Train the Model
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=len(training_images)//batch_size,
                              epochs=10,
                              validation_steps=len(testing_images)//batch_size
                              )

# model.evaluate(testing_images/255., testing_labels, verbose=0)

# Plot the chart for accuracy and loss on both training and validation
acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs = range(len(acc))

plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r', label='Training accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation accuracy')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.figure()

plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'r', label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

but the loss rate almost doesn't change...

```
Epoch 1/10
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_train_function.<locals>.train_function at 0x0000026B4B18F948> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
2022-01-27 09:40:05.564400: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2022-01-27 09:40:05.743540: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2022-01-27 09:40:06.492580: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation.
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
430/437 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.1891 - accuracy: 0.0461WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_test_function.<locals>.test_function at 0x0000026B490A4F78> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 3.1890 - accuracy: 0.0463 - val_loss: 3.2067 - val_accuracy: 0.0230
Epoch 2/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 3.1828 - accuracy: 0.0425 - val_loss: 3.1952 - val_accuracy: 0.0333
Epoch 3/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 3.1802 - accuracy: 0.0401 - val_loss: 3.2006 - val_accuracy: 0.0230
Epoch 4/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 3.1789 - accuracy: 0.0434 - val_loss: 3.2012 - val_accuracy: 0.0348
Epoch 5/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 3.1782 - accuracy: 0.0448 - val_loss: 3.2109 - val_accuracy: 0.0345
Epoch 6/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 3.1784 - accuracy: 0.0454 - val_loss: 3.2056 - val_accuracy: 0.0230
Epoch 7/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 3.1782 - accuracy: 0.0407 - val_loss: 3.2032 - val_accuracy: 0.0230
Epoch 8/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 3.1780 - accuracy: 0.0391 - val_loss: 3.2080 - val_accuracy: 0.0230
Epoch 9/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 3.1775 - accuracy: 0.0417 - val_loss: 3.2033 - val_accuracy: 0.0230
Epoch 10/10
418/437 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.1773 - accuracy: 0.0460Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with this network is, learning too fast.
if you set the learning rate from 0.005 to 0.0005, this model works fine.

```
# Compile Model.
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Do not learn too fast, or you will stuck in a local minimum and never get out.**

```
Epoch 2/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 2.5773 - accuracy: 0.2133 - val_loss: 2.2050 - val_accuracy: 0.3542
Epoch 3/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 2.1190 - accuracy: 0.3262 - val_loss: 1.6197 - val_accuracy: 0.5278
Epoch 4/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: 1.7566 - accuracy: 0.4223 - val_loss: 1.3985 - val_accuracy: 0.5492
Epoch 5/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.5062 - accuracy: 0.4929 - val_loss: 1.1146 - val_accuracy: 0.7000
Epoch 6/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.3736 - accuracy: 0.5323 - val_loss: 1.0778 - val_accuracy: 0.6756
Epoch 7/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.2198 - accuracy: 0.5836 - val_loss: 0.8912 - val_accuracy: 0.7650
Epoch 8/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.1396 - accuracy: 0.6066 - val_loss: 0.8298 - val_accuracy: 0.7486
Epoch 9/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.1084 - accuracy: 0.6182 - val_loss: 0.9152 - val_accuracy: 0.6830
Epoch 10/10
437/437 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 1.0196 - accuracy: 0.6525 - val_loss: 0.8014 - val_accuracy: 0.7307
```

BTW: the efficiency of the reading method is not very 'python'. This works better.

```
def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as training_file:
        raw_file = np.loadtxt(training_file.readlines()[
                              :-1], dtype=float, skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
        labels=np.array([i[0] for i in raw_file])
        images=np.array([i[1:785] for i in raw_file])
        images=images.reshape(-1,28,28)
        print(f'read file:{filename} complete')
        return images, labels
```